# How to reduce sampling plot area by a border made up by three border points measured with distance and angle from the plot centre?

Tags: r, geometry

How do I calculate the portion of my sampling plot framed by the border points of my sampling plot (the shaded area in the figure)?

[image]

All angles were measured in gon. The first border point is the vertex of the two border lines. Any help would be very appreciated... My dataframe looks simular to this:

```
Plot_ID<-c(1,2)
Point_1_dist<-c(5,3)
Point_2_dist<-c(10,14)
Point_3_dist<-c(12,5)

Point_1_ang<-c(380,400)
Point_2_ang<-c(360,370)
Point_3_ang<-c(50,34)
Sampling_plot_radius<-c(12,12)
df <- data.frame(Plot_ID,Point_1_dist, Point_1_ang,Point_2_dist,Point_2_ang,Point_3_dist,Point_3_ang,Sampling_plot_radius)
```

Comment: Have you tried calculating it as the sum of the area of the triangle joined by the 3 points, plus the shaded area of the segment of the circle that is outside that triangle?  You can find formulas for both of those on Google.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to try this, but first I need to find a way how to get the measurements for the angles/sites from the triangle. I just have the angles and distances measured from the plot centre to the 3 points.